# References in Beamer presentation

Tags: beamer

I want to use Latex for a presentation and need to insert some references. It seems nice to me to insert them in brackets right under the "main text" of the bullet point.

The following code comes close to my expectation:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{setspace}

\newcommand{\quotednew}[2]{{\setstretch{0.5} #1 \\ \hfill \begin{tiny} \textcolor{gray}{(#2)} \end{tiny}\\}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{bla}

\begin{itemize}
\item \quotednew{blabblabblabblabblabblabblabblabblabbl abblabblabblabblabblabblabblab}{Mustermann, 2005}
\item \quotednew{blabblabblabblabblabblabblabblabblabbl abblabblabblabblabblabblabblab}{Mustermann, 2005}
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

What is anoying with this code is that the "main text" of the bullet point (blab…) is also close together (setspace{0.5}). I would like to have the "main text" of the bullet point in regular spacing which is setspace{1.0} and only the reference (Mustermann, 2005) appear in setspace{0.5} right under the bottom of the "main text."

Hope it is clear what I mean. Anyone has an idea for how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way by replacing your `\setstretch` with an optional argument in each new line (\):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{setspace}

\newcommand{\quotednew}[2]{#1 \\[-0.5ex] \hfill \begin{tiny} \textcolor{gray}{(#2)} \end{tiny}\\[0.5ex]}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{bla}

\begin{itemize}
\item \quotednew{blabblabblabblabblabblabblabblabblabbl abblabblabblabblabblabblabblab}{Mustermann, 2005}
\item \quotednew{blabblabblabblabblabblabblabblabblabbl abblabblabblabblabblabblabblab}{Mustermann, 2005}
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

You could use any value up to 1ex and the result (for - and +1ex) would be :

[image]

Comment: You could replace with any value between -0.5ex and -1ex and change the added value to the same (but positive) to have your desired spaces.